# Can i wait for "waitForTaskToken" in lambda function (aws) more then it's timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

Here i have a question like if i have state function state which invoke lambda with wait for task token. The default timeout of lambda is 3 sec but i chnaged it to 2mins.

can i call another service from lambda function which take more then 2 min, and how to call that service.

Comment: Yes, you can, but it will throw timed-out error. Just call it.

Comment: You can. Pass the taskToken to the other service and let that service perform the callback. That is, as long as your lambda doesn't need to do more work beyond what the other service does. If so, maybe they should be separate tasks in the step function.